# Increase the panel pane title length

Tags: views, panels

There is a module for increasing the node title, but how to increase the maximum length of a panel pane title?
I have a view pane which title must be overwritten in its panel pane settings. This works fine, but while appending extra tokens and styling to the title I bumped into the maximum length available.
How can this be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Do not put styling in pane title, move html/css in a template file, you can override next templates for that: panels-pane.tpl.php or views-view.tpl.php